# How to hide unnecessary reorder arrows in list

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, wai-aria

But the top list should have only down arrow and bottom list should have only up arrow after reordering.

i have tried below [image: example image]

[check this code](http://jsfiddle.net/nvcL2rxv/)

```js
$('#testidone ul li').append('<span ><img class="down-arrow" id="theImg" src="grey-darrow.png" tabindex="0" /><img class="up-arrow" id="2img" src="theImg.png" tabindex="0" /></span>');

$('#testidone ul li:first span img.up-arrow').css("visibility", "hidden");
$('#testidone ul li:last span img.down-arrow').css("visibility", "hidden");

newt = $('#testidone ul li span img');
$(newt).keydown(function(e) {
  var pli = $(this).parent().parent("li");

  if ($("img.down-arrow").is(":focus")) {
    switch (e.which) {

      case 40:
        pli.insertAfter(pli.next());
        break; //down


    }
    pli.focus();
  }
});




$("li").parent().css("background-color", "yellow");
```

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="testidone">
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="testidtwo">
  <ul>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Please try to attach your code again. It's not showing

Comment: What is your problem ? What is your question ?

Comment: by using up and down arrow images we have to reorder list but top list should not have up arrow and bottom list should not have down arrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $('#testidone ul li').append('<span ><img class="down-arrow" id="theImg"      src="grey-darrow.png" tabindex="0" data-direction="down" /><img class="up-arrow" id="2img" src="theImg.png" tabindex="0" data-direction="up"/></span>');

    function setFirstLast(){
        $('#testidone ul li:first span img.up-arrow').css("visibility","hidden"); 
        $('#testidone ul li:last span img.down-arrow').css("visibility","hidden");
    }
    setFirstLast();
    $("#testidone ul li img").click(function(){
        var parentEle = $(this).parent().parent("li");
        if($(this).hasClass( "down-arrow" )){
            $('#testidone ul li:first span img.up-arrow').css("visibility","visible"); 
            parentEle.insertAfter(parentEle.next());
        }
        else{
            $('#testidone ul li:last span img.down-arrow').css("visibility","visible");
            parentEle.insertBefore(parentEle.prev());
        }
        setFirstLast();
    });
    $("li").parent().css( "background-color", "yellow" );
```

Comment: by using up and down arrow images we have to reorder list but top list should not have up arrow and bottom list should not have down arrow

Comment: Then there should there should be any fixed index which have to move both direction.

Comment: you have implemeted using on click  events it should be reordered through up and down keyboard arrows.

Comment: almost correct but it should not reorder with tab only with arrow key

Comment: switch (e.which) {

      case 38:
        pli.insertBefore(pli.prev());
        break; //down


    }

Comment: using this we can almost achieve else if(e.which==38){, but focus should come to first left arrow when right arrow is not there

Comment: I believe your requirement is full by this, vote me for this answer